# How to fast change current active browser's tab using js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, tabs, google-chrome-devtools

is there any way to write simple function in js to instantly change active browser tab? For example: I have active tab A, open console, write the function, run it and have tab B as currently active tab (instead of tab A)? Is it possible?

Comment: Is that just in your browsers, or is it in an app, or is it in a browser extension? Also which browser(s)?

Comment: just in my browser (chrome). Is there any way to switch tabs using function called when different tab is active?

Comment: I know that Chrome has an API for tabs but I'm not aware of the specifics. I don't know if it's possible from just the console or from an extension - I've added the chrome and chrome devtools tags to your question, as somebody else might know and those will help with finding the question. Sorry I can't help.